# Short Code Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've written a regex to match a short code in the format similar to:

```
[playername Le'Veon Bell]
```

Here is the regex:

```
\[playername\s+(?<name>[\w \-\'\’]+)\s*\]
```

I know the regex is struggling with the single quote in the player name. I've tested the regex [here](http://regexhero.net/tester) and it appears to work, but is not finding the match when I run the code from my web app.

Comment: Could you give us a more complete example? Something that includes a full string and more than one example of a match?

Comment: your code works fine for me http://ideone.com/c4iSbf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information you provided I believe `\[playername\s+(?<name>[^]]+?)\s*\]` should work.

The only real difference is in the capture group `[^]]+` which matches any character that is NOT a `]`. This will effectively capture anything after `[playername` up until the *first* `]`. It'll break if you have nested brackets.

Comment: I would probably use an anchor so the name doesn't have trailing whitespace. `\[playername\s+(?<name>[^]]+?)\s*\]`

Comment: @Joshua you must need to add `?` and `\s*` in your regex.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I added the `?` for the lazy (non-greedy) match but whether it's necessary is somewhat debatable. The final `\s*` won't do much since the character class will capture any spaces between the last character and the closing bracket. The captured value should be trimmed after retrieval.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: ah, I see, when combined with the lazy operator it actually works out a little better. Thanks, I'll amend it!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following regex:

```
\[playername\s+(?<name>.*?)\s*\]
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dH9eM6/1)

Comment: Maybe you can point out anchoring the regex (multiline) or using lazy for `.*` when grouping from a large string as well. Since the original regex allows whitespaces before `\]` outside capturing group, might want to have that back in.

Answer (score 2):

For this example, you don't need to escape `-`,`'` symbols which are present inside the character class.

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\[playername\s+(?<name>[\w '’-]+?)\s*\]");
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/1BMhPp)

Comment: Careful: space-hyphen-apostrophe in a character class matches space, `!`, `"`, `#`, `$`, `%`, `&` and `'`, and not `-`.

Comment: i think now it seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your scenario it's kind of difficult to say for sure, but from what you've got, I'd say you should switch to something more like this?

```
\[playername\s+(?<name>[^\]\s]*)\s+\]
```

That will match anything that doesn't have a square bracket or space in it, so it seems like what you're actually trying to do. I'd personally be tempted to remove the whitespace conditions, just on the grounds that a name might have a space in it. You could always call whatever your language's version of C#'s `string.Trim()` is post-facto.

Note, of course, that it isn't exactly the same as what you're doing: you're limiting the characters explicitly. But it looks like you're trying to limit to any text anyway.